# Testing promises within promises

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, mocha.js

I used to have the following code:

```
function makeCall(userInfo) {
  api.postUser(userInfo).then(response => {
    utils.redirect(response.url);
  })

  // other logic
  return somethingElse;
}
```

And I was able to write a test that looked like this:

```
const successPromise = Promise.resolve({ url: 'successUrl' })

beforeEach(function() {
  sinon.stub(api.postUser).returns(successPromise);
}

afterEach(function() {
  api.postUser.restore();
}

it "calls API properly and redirects" do
  makeCall({});  
  expect(api.postUser).calledWith(userInfo).toBe(true);
  successPromise.then(() => {
    expect(utils.redirect.calledWith('successUrl')).toBe(true);
    done();
  }
emd
```

And everything was green.

Now, I had to add another promise to make another external call, before doing the api postUser call, so my code looks like this:

```
function makeCall(names) {
  fetchUserData(names).then(userData => {
    return api.postUser(userData).then(response => {
     utils.redirect(response.url);
    })
  })

  // other logic
  return somethingElse;
 }
```

where fetchUseData is a chain of many promises, such like:

```
function fetchNames(names) {
  // some name regions
  return Promise.all(names);
}
function fetchUserData(names) {
  fetchUsersByNames(names).then(users => {
    // For now we just choose first user
    {
      id: users[0].id,
      name: users[0].name,
    }
  });
}
```

And the tests I had fail. I am trying to understand how to change my tests to make sure that I am still testing that I do the final API call properly and the redirect is also done. I want to stub what `fetchUserData(names)`, to prevent doing that HTTP call.

Comment: You're not using promises correctly. Your code doesn't have a single `return` statement, when it should have several (or it should at least be using arrow functions in such a way that you don't need them, which you're not doing). You keep referring to a free-floating block of code as "my code". What is calling that code? Shouldn't your tests be calling it? They seem to be observing some result after your code has already run somewhere else.

Comment: Try returning the inner promise (add `return`) to create a promise chain.

Comment: @JLRishe updated. My main concern is where should I be putting the `done()` or what should I be doing so the promises are stubbed and evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using promises correctly. Your code doesn't have a single `return` statement, when it should have several (or it should be using arrow functions in such a way that you don't need them, which you're not doing).

Fix your code:

```
function makeCall(names) {
  // v---- return
  return fetchUserData(names).then(userData => {
    // v---- return
    return api.postUser(userData).then(response => {
      utils.redirect(response.url);
    })
  })
 }


function fetchUserData(names) {
  // v---- return
  return fetchUsersByNames(names).then(users => {
    // For now we just choose first user
    // v---- return
    return {
      id: users[0].id,
      name: users[0].name,
    }
  });
}
```

Once you've done that, you can have your test wait for all of the operations to finish.

Test code:

```
makeCall(['name']).then(() =>
  expect(api.postUser).calledWith(userInfo).toBe(true);
  expect(utils.redirect.calledWith('successUrl')).toBe(true);
  done();
});
```

Comment: hey JLRishe, what if I don't want to return the promise in the most outer function? It's a side effect, and I want to return something else (the reason being is that this is being used in a redux middleware, and you always need to return the `next(action)`. I have edited my question to explain why I don't have a return on that last promise, but rather treat it as a side effect of the function.

Comment: @HommerSmith It sounds like you might be trying to mix two incompatible  paradigms. It looks like redux middleware has its own way of dealing with asynchrony that's very different from promises. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about redux middleware, but [here's some information on using it with promises](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=redux+middleware+promises&oq=redux+middleware+promises&aqs=chrome..69i64.4271j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks JLRishe. I guess since my tests were passing when I just had a promise (even if it was not returning), I thought that when I added more promises into that initial promise, I could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a return statement, otherwise you are not returning promises nowhere:

```
function fetchNames(names) {
  // some name regions
  return Promise.all(names);
}
function fetchUserData(names) {
  return fetchUsersByNames(names).then(users => {
    // For now we just choose first user
    {
      id: users[0].id,
      name: users[0].name,
    }
  });
}
```

So when you are using Promise.all(), then you will have as result of the promise an array with all the value returned by all the promises. 
So then this method should look like this when called:

```
fetchNames(names).then((arrayOfResolvedPromises) => {
 // here you will have all your promised resolved and the array holds all the results
});
```

So inside your test you can move your done inside the block where *all* the promises will be resolved.

In addition, I strongly suggest you to use a library as chai-as-promised for testing promises. 
It has a lot of nice methods for testing your promises.

https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised

Comment: That doesn't make my tests pass. Where should I put the `done()` if I have several promises?

Comment: You need to keep all the promise inside a Promise.all(). Inside its then block you are sure that all the promises have been resolved